# Convert List<object> to class of Objects : List<object>

Tags: c#

Is it possible to convert a `List<Document>` to a class of `Documents : List<Document>`

For instance, I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class Documents : List<Document>
{

}
```

But I need to convert my `List<Document>` to `Documents`.

(Lack of information on this leads me to believe it is either not possible, or I am gravely mis-using these objects.

Comment: You can't. You will need to construct a new `Document` object. A simple casting will not work.

Comment: It's not recommended to subclass `List<T>`. Perhaps you should implement `IEnumerable<Document>` and pass in the list to `Documents`? If `Documents` does not have any implementation, however, it's better to simply use `List<Document>` rather than `Documents`

Comment: @Rob  By pass in, you mean.... ?

Comment: @beardedmogul Provide `Documents` with a list of documents in the constructor, or as a property.

Comment: why do you want another class? is there any extra functionality or property you want to add?

Comment: There's no clarity regarding the use case, why do you need it, provide ore details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method #1

There is currently no default builtin way to cast `List<Object>` to `Objects : List<object>`, but instead you could [kind of clone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) the list:

```
public static Documents CastToDocuments(this List<Document> docs)
{
    var toRet = new Documents();
    toRet.AddRange(docs);
    return toRet;
}
```

I do also highly suggest reading another question on SO that already asked [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

### Method #2

I just got the idea, that you could add a private list inside your `Documents` class and implement *`basic list logic`* and a `ToList()` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a list of documents.
/// </summary>
public class Documents
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises the private list of documents.
    /// </summary>
    public Documents()
    {
        _docs = new List<Document>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a speified document.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="doc">This document will be added to the saved documents.</param>
    public void Add(Document doc)
    {
        _docs.Add(doc);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove a specific document.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="doc">This document will be removed from the saved documents.</param>
    public void Remove(Document doc)
    {
        _docs.Remove(doc);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all saved documents.
    /// </summary>
    public void Clear()
    {
        _docs.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// "Casts" this instance to a list of documents.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns all documents inside a list.</returns>
    public List<Document> ToList() => _docs;

    /// <summary>
    /// A list of documents.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly List<Document> _docs;
}
```

This seems a bit nicer to use because of the following benefits:

- A nice wrapper for `Document`
- More security on the actual list
- More control of the list
- The ability to only implement methods, that you really need
- (And if you need the features of a list, than you could still just return your secure list!)

Comment: Good read, but our situations are different.  _Documents_, in this situation, is simply a list of _Document_.  I was just looking for a cleaner way to have plural _Document_.

Comment: @beardedmogul added a _cleaner_ method!

Comment: I, by chance, revisited this answer, and can I just say, Method 2 is genius :)  I didn't totally understand what the outcome would be, and although I still don't entirely understand what it's doing, I do enough to implement it.  However, I have a problem.  I am having trouble implementing a 'Where' on it.  Would you be so kind as to help me?

Comment: @beardedmogul Great to hear! :) I will work out a solution later on, but meanwhile you could simple use the Where method on ToList(). Simple, but effective ;)

Comment: I did actually get a working solution. My problem was that I had it executing on an already initialized object, so if I ran the 'where' once, it worked as I would expect, but running it again evaluated only on the previous 'where's results.  I changed it to copy the current object and return a 'where' on the copied data, leaving the original object untouched.

Comment: Interesting. Normally Where does not alter the current list, but rather returns the result as a copy (list) of the found items! How exactly does your solution look like?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it looked like this:

`public DataObjects Where(System.Func<string, bool> p)`
`{`
    `return dataObjects.Where(p);`
`}`

(I forget what a predicate exactly looks like :-/   I'm at work. I can post my code when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert object of base class to derived class in general and `List<T>` to `MyType : List<T>` in particular.

The only option without changing design is to construct new instance of `Documents` and copy add items from original list to that new instance (possibly there is constructor that takes list as argument).